# Set Permission of a module in magento

Tags: magento, module

How we can set the permission of a custom module in magento?

I have installed a module and try to set the permission in the adminpanel but the module is not appearing in the Role List.
But Its not working.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ACL needs to be set in the config.xml OR in adminhtml.xml (if in config.xml enclose in `<adminhtml>`).

```
<acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <your_mod_menu translate="title" module="your_mod">
                        <title>MOD TITLE</title>
                        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <your_mod_news translate="title" module="your_mod">
                                <title> Manage Mod</title>
                                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                            </your_mod_news>
                            <your_mod_store translate="title" module="your_mod">
                                <title>Store Settings</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </your_mod_store>
                            <your_mod_sub translate="title" module="your_mod">
                                <title>Manage Subscribers</title>
                                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                            </your_mod_sub>
                        </children>
                    </your_mod_menu>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
```